# How can i let class methods interact with a context manager in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code contains some objects which are used via Pythons "with" statement to ensure that they get savely closed.

Now i want to create a class where the methods can interact with these objects.

For example my code actually looks like this:

```
with ... as a, with ... as b:
    # do something with a and b here
    call_method(a, b)  # pass a and b here
```

I'd like to put it into a class, so it Looks "like" this:

```
class Something(object):

    def __init__(self):
        with ... as a:
            self.a = a
        with ... as b:
            self.b = b

    def do_something(self):
        # do something with self.a and self.b
        self.call_method(self.a, self.b)

    def call_method(self, a, b)
        # do more with a, b
```

The objects need to stay "opened" all the time.

I don't know how to achieve this, so how can i do this?

Comment: Then don't use `with`, just close the files manually. You don't have a context here that is being exited.

Comment: And how does that solution ensure that the files get closed securely on an exception?

Comment: Use `try:`, `finally:` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a 'context' in your class to manage, don't use `with` in `__init__`. You'll have to close the files in some other manner.

You can always use `try:`, `finally:` if you want the file objects to be closed if there is an exception *within the method*:

```
def call_method(self, a, b)
    try:
        # do more with a, b
    finally:
        self.a.close()
        self.b.close()
```

but it depends heavily on what you wanted to do with the files if you really wanted them to be closed at that point.

If your instances themselves should be used in a specific context (e.g. there is a block of code than starts and ends during which your instance should have the file open), then you can make the *class* a context manager by implementing the [context manager special methods](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers).

You alone as designer of the class API will know how long the files need to stay open for. It depends heavily on how the instance is used when it is time to close the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your class itself a context manager:

```
class Something(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __enter__(self):
        self.a_e = a.__enter__(self)
        self.b_e = b.__enter__(self)
    def __exit__(self, *x):
        xb = False
        try:
            xb = self.b_e(*x)
        finally:
            xa = self.a_e(*x)
        return xa or xb # make sure both are called.
    def do_something(self):
        # do something with self.a and self.b
        # - or, if present, with a_e, b_e
        self.call_method(self.a, self.b)
    def call_method(self, a, b)
        # do more with a, b
```

**This is just the raw idea**. In order to make it work properly, you must do even more with `try:` `except:` `finally:`.

You can use it then with

```
with Something(x, y) as sth:
    sth.do_something()
```

and it gets properly `__enter__()`ed and `__exit__()`ed.

Comment: Well, the problem is that i dont want to pass a and b all the time from one method to another, what i'm looking for is a way to make multiple methods use these objects.